# DartEditor doesn't like spectre examples

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I'm looking into migrating an app from JavaScript and kineticjs to dart and spectre. I've downloaded spectre and run "pub install" in the top directory where the pubspec.yaml file is located. This creates packages directory and populates for all the examples.

I then opened the directory of one of the examples in DartEditor which is unable to resolve the various imports in the source files. All the dependencies appear to have been downloaded into the packages directory of the example but DartEditor doesn't like the import URI's is there a way to clear these highlighted errors?

As an example the line:
import 'package:asset_pack/asset_pack.dart';
is highlighted in red as the URI doesn't exist but in the packages directory created by "pub install" is the directory "asset_pack" containing the necessary file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your environment is not configured correctly. What OS are you running on?

John